# What is switchMap equivalent to in unflattened form?

Tags: rxjs, rxjs5

If `flatMap()` is equivalent to `map().mergeAll()`,
then what is `switchMap()` equivalent to ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `switchMap()` operator is equivalent to using `map().switch()`.

Since the `switch()` operator works only with higher-order Observables the preceding `map()` has to return an Observable. There's no `switchAll()` operator because the `switch()` operator already works with higher-order Observables(just like all `*all()` operators).