# Why switch can be used as an instance operator while merge and concat can't

Tags: javascript, rxjs

We have 3 frequently used operators that work with Observables sequence - `mergeMap`, `concatMap`, and `switchMap`. Suppose I have the following observables:

```
const os = [
    Rx.Observable.interval(400).take(3).map((i) => `a${i}`),
    Rx.Observable.interval(400).take(3).map((i) => `b${i}`),
    Rx.Observable.interval(400).take(3).map((i) => `c${i}`)
];
```

The `switch` operator can be used to work with a sequence of observables:

```
Rx.Observable.interval(1000).take(os.length).map((i) => os[i]).switch().subscribe((v) => console.log(v));
```

And it can also work if this sequence of observables generated from the map using `switchMap`:

```
Rx.Observable.interval(1000).take(os.length).switchMap((i) => os[i]).subscribe((v) => console.log(v));
```

The other two operators `mergeMap` and `concatMap` can also work with the observables generated from the `map`. And I can also use them to combine observables:

```
Rx.Observable.merge(os[0], os[1], os[2]).subscribe((v) => console.log(v));
Rx.Observable.concat(os[0], os[1], os[2]).subscribe((v) => console.log(v));
```

But my question is why they can't be used like `switch` to work on the stream of observables?

```
Rx.Observable.interval(1000).take(os.length).map((i) => os[i]).merge().subscribe((v) => console.log(v));
Rx.Observable.interval(1000).take(os.length).map((i) => os[i]).concat().subscribe((v) => console.log(v));
```

What prevents the implementation? I'm curious to know the underlying constrains.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I've seen exactly the same question here already. You don't use `concat()` and `merge()` in this way because there are already `concatAll()` and `mergeAll()` operators to do the exact same thing as you want.

Similarly there's no `switchAll()` or `switch(obs1, obs2)`. `switchAll()` doesn't make sense because `switch()` already works with higher-order Observables.
Then there's no `switch(obs1, obs2)` because you can simply use `.merge(obs1, obs2).switch()` to achieve the same.

Comment: I think this was the related question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/43165848/6680611

Comment: thanks, so basically `map().mergeAll()` is the same as `mergeMap`? the same way as `map().switch()` is the same as `switchMap()`?

Comment: any comment on that previous quesiton?\